# Is Math.random() reliable?

Tags: javascript, random

I am using Math.random to generate velocities for my project but my function seems to be returning biased numbers.

This is my random function. It generates a value from -1 to 1.

```
x_velocity += ((Math.random() * 2) - 1);
y_velocity += ((Math.random() * 2) - 1);
```

[image: Result of Code]

As seen in this picture, the velocities are not random. They should be scattered all throughout the circle but they move towards the top left. This behavior continues after refreshing.

Edit: I found the error. A bit later in the program, I edited the particles to move upwards for debugging but forgot to delete that part out.

Comment: Scattered throughout the circle doesn't mean random.

Comment: Your values occur in a region with square borders. How are you mapping them to a circle? I'd suspect a flaw in your mapping algorithm. Also, you're `+=`ing the velocities; what is their base value?

Comment: Their base value is zero. The Math.random generates a value between -1 and 1 and adds it to the x and y velocities. Then the x and y velocities are added to the x and y coordinates of the dots.

Comment: @BrianNguyen When are these values added? Repeatedly in a `requestAnimationFrame`? Only once?

Comment: @user4642212 They are being added in `requestAnimationFrame` function.

Comment: @BrianNguyen Then I can’t reproduce this behavior on either Chrome or Firefox. Please [edit] your question and provide a [mre] demonstrating the issue. It doesn’t need to contain all the fancy colors, just the bare minimum to understand why the velocities behave like this. Did any of the hints and answers so far help?

Answer (score 1):

How about uniform in circle sampling

```
let r = Math.sqrt(Math.random());
let phi = 2.0*Math.PI*Math.random();
let x_velocity = r*Math.cos(phi);
let y_velocity = r*Math.sin(phi);
```

Comment: @user4642212 good point, answer edited